# Cannot run the MQTT Broker Service

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

At first, when i set the

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

in mosquitto.conf,
i can run the mqtt broker service by "net start mosquitto" in CMD and it worked when i checked the services. But when I change it into

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
password_file C:\Program Files\mosquitto\passwd
```

I cannot run the mqtt broker anymore athough in CMD it has successfully. When I tried to run mqtt broker directly on servicecs, it said

```
The Mosquitto Broker service on Local Storage started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs
```

I have tried to reinstall it so many times and I still get this error.

Answer (score 3):

You can always test your config file by explicitly running it from the command line with

```
mosquitto -c c:\full\path\to\mosquitto.conf
```

You should stop the service first so as not to clash on the port used.

In this case it would likely have printed an error about being unable to find the password file because it has a space in the path. You should be able to fix this by wrapping it in quotes:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
password_file "C:\Program Files\mosquitto\passwd"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!. Your suggestions are very valuable. I solved this problem by typing ".\mosquitto.exe -v -c mosquitto.conf" before I pub and sub in the CMD to run MQTT Broker first.